Obtain a view or reference to a list node in C#
Instead of using a ringbuffer for a polygon, where I need to copy elements when removing one item, I'd like to do this efficiently with a list, with O(1) overhead for removing any item and O(1) access to the currently updated next element without requiring special cases such as ringbuffer wrapping. No allocations are required.
In summary, I am asking for a simple datastructure with O(1) remove/insert operation, O(1) local (i.e. relative) element access, which doesn't require me to handle special cases as wrapping around ends.
The way such a data structure works is that you can modify and access the list from previously retrieved elements. It is common in natural language expression to say something like "Add x before and after the minimum value".
I'd like to know, if C# has a method for obtaining such a node reference (or "node view") element which allows me to obtain the next node element, access the node's value, remove elements with O(1) and without the arbitrary limitation of an immutable list.
In C++ e.g., it could look like this:
template<typename T> struct ListNode {
    struct List *list;
    ListNode *next, *previous;
    T *value;

    ListNode* insertAfter(T *newValue);
    ListNode* insertBefore(T *newValue);
    void removeFromList();
    void destroy();
};
struct List {
    ListNode *firstNode, *lastNode;
    unsigned int length;
};

(Don't mind the code or the memory management, I only wrote it for better understanding. This snippet should be pretty similar to a C# snippet in unsafe context with pointers.)
I could also implement my own generic list type but a custom implementation is not what I want. I'd like to know if libraries or features shipped with .NET releases provide a direct solution for this general concept.

This should be possible. Can you attempt to write it in C# first?

what is .NET here?
The built-in types from .NET BCL, i.e. LinkedList?

@tinmanjk Probably yes, I am not even sure what the difference between BCL and FCL is, any "class library" that is shipped with the C# release. Otherwise, if you know 3rd party library, it is likely sufficient for a basic answer.

standard library, BCL = FCL for all intents and purposes. It's shipped with .NET releases, not c#
